# Issue in Inner Join Query in Android | Trouble in Sqlite query

Tags: android, sqlite, inner-join

I am in trouble I have 2 table in sqlite and want both field from them but I did not got any thing. I have tried a lot on stack overflow but no one is work for me..
My query is something like that-

```
public List<HeadItemGroup> getAllExpense() {
            List<HeadItemGroup> expenseList = new ArrayList<HeadItemGroup>();
            db = sqlHp.getReadableDatabase();
            String selectquery = "SELECT table_expense.item_id AS ID,table_item.item_id AS ID2,* FROM table_expense INNER JOIN table_item ON table_expense.item_id=table_item.item_id";
            System.out.println("selectquery value..."+selectquery);
            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    HeadItemGroup record = new HeadItemGroup();
                    record.setExpId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENCE_ID)));
                    record.setItemId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ITEM_ID)));
                    record.setHeadId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(HEAD_ID)));
                    record.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENCE_DATE)));
                    record.setPrice(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENCE_PRICE)));
                    record.setLocationLat(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LOCATION_LAT)));
                    record.setLocationLon(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LOCATION_LON)));
                    record.setLocationName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LOCATION_NAME)));
                    record.setCurrency(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CURRENCY_SYMBOL)));
                    record.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DESCRIPTION)));
                    record.setItemName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ITEM_NAME)));
                    record.setGroupId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(GROUP_ID)));

                    expenseList.add(record);
                    System.out.println("total value value**************"+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EXPENCE_PRICE)));
                    System.out.println("total value value**************"+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ITEM_NAME)));
                    System.out.println("total value value**************"+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(GROUP_ID)));
            }

            return expenseList;
        }
```

And when I am trying with same table for left outer join it's work..

```
String selectquery="select exp_id as _id, * from table_expense d left outer join table_item  u on ( d.item_id=u.item_id)";
```

But i need all data from both table. Please help me...

Comment: Sounds like your tables don't have any matching data. If they do, you'll need to add some sample data to the question to repeat the problem.

Comment: I have item_id... I checked it manually..

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson any other thing may be i am missing?

Comment: An inner join will only return rows where there is matching data in _both_ tables. That a LEFT JOIN returns data indicates that there is no common item_id between the tables.

Comment: But dear, i am using same query in sqlite browser and it's return all field..

Comment: And i can't use LEFT JOIN because i want both table data..

Comment: J@JoachimIsaksson But dear, i am using same query in sqlite browser and it's return all field.

Comment: I can't help you in this topic..