# How to save Image in shared preference?

Tags: image, save, shared, preference

How to save Image in shared preference in Android | Shared preference issue in Android with Image.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072448/how-to-save-image-in-shared-preference-in-android-shared-preference-issue-in-a/45707580#45707580

Answer (score 0):

You can save base64String of image