# Android Imageview to set image permanently

Tags: android-imageview

In my project i have an imageview to set profile picture either from camera or gallery, but my problem was when am set images it will be showed in imageview but while close and open my application means it will be removed how to set images permanently... Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

You may use SharedPrefrences to store values permanently.Check out this link

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: thanks for replying, i am know about sharedpreferences but i have some doubt about where to use in my program

Comment: May be this link can help you solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072448/how-to-save-image-in-shared-preference-in-android-shared-preference-issue-in-a