# How to get the Image into Shared Preferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I need to save my static image view to the shared preference, so that i can fit in the image to the HTML document. I even did try by encoding and decoding the Bitmap image using Base64.

```java
public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image) {
    Bitmap bImage = image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imageEncoded;
}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
    byte[] decodeByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeByte, 0, decodeByte.length);
}
```

Comment: you can save your image in asset folder

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you put the code of encoding and decoding?

Comment: the thing is i dont need to get the image in any particular activity, i just need it to be saved as a shared preference key so that  i could retrieve it in the HTML code

Comment: ``` public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image){
        Bitmap bImage = image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return imageEncoded;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input){
        byte[] decodeByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeByte, 0, decodeByte.length);
    }
```

Comment: Please add it to the question... and what error is giving to you when you using this code? Or what the actual result of using it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072448/how-to-save-image-in-shared-preference-in-android-shared-preference-issue-in-a

Comment: Hello please check out this link for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072448/how-to-save-image-in-shared-preference-in-android-shared-preference-issue-in-a